# Spring server.session.timeout not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session

I am trying to increase User session to say 60 min. Can't figure it out. Same issue with SpringBoot versions 1.4.2 and 1.5.7: always default to 30 min.

Tried to change `application.properties` like this:

```
...
server.session.timeout=34444600 // very long time
...
```

Not working. Probably because I am using Spring JDBC sessions (sessions saved in DB).

Then, when I set the timeout when I enable JDBC HTTP Session:

```
/**
 * This Spring configuration is responsible for creating a Servlet
 * Filter that replaces the HttpSession
 * implementation with an implementation backed by Spring Session.
 */
@EnableJdbcHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 60000)
public class HttpSessionConfig {
// empty: nothing needed.
}
```

Notice `maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds` above with a very long timeout. This does not work either.

How do I increase the session timeout?

Comment: I think you also need to play with `server.session.cookie.max-age` too, I guess it would make sense to keep both settings to same value.

Comment: @Zeronex `server.session.cookie.max-age` did the trick. If you make an answer, I'll check it off.